# Failed to resolve: com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.9. in Build.grade

Tags: android

Hey guys I'm trying to add the cards library for my android app by adding this line to my projects build.grade file:

```
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.9.1'
```

However when I re-sync the grade file i get this error:

Failed to resolve: com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.9.1

heres my build.grade file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Will compile all the Libraries inside the 'libs' folder
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.9.1'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the maintools source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }


}
```

I'm new to android studio so any help I can get on this error would be amazing!

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: Use the cards that come with AppCompat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fix was to create new classes/layouts and copy all items from the eclipse project into the android studio project that uses the card library all is working fine now thanks to everyone who tried to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Please check on the Gradle panel (usually placed on the right side of the screen) that offline mode is not switched on.

*EDIT*

Also, I don't see `repositories` section in your build file (a standalone one, not under `buildscript`), please try adding:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: offline mode is Not on. any other suggestions??

Comment: added the lines of code you suggested and still am having the same issue any other suggestions?

Comment: @Phoneswapshop hard to say, I have no problem syncing with your file on my project. Can you also show your top-level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Thank you for all your help since this app was imported into android studio form eclipse it only has the one grade file any other advice? Thanks for all your help!